# Executing a dtsx from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have problem with executing package from stored procedure. WHen job finishes, I get error:

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 11.0.2100.60
>   for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   NULL Started:  09:47:51 Error: 2014-06-11 09:47:51.34    Code:
>   0xC0011007    Source: {4B0EFACA-9BE8-4E0B-AEF7-A1453AF75271}
>   Description: Unable to load the package as XML because of package does
>   not have a valid XML format. A specific XML parser error will be
>   posted. End Error Error: 2014-06-11 09:47:51.34    Code: 0xC0011002
>   Source: {4B0EFACA-9BE8-4E0B-AEF7-A1453AF75271}     Description: Failed
>   to open package file "\server\path\Package.dtsx" due to error
>   0x80070005 "Access is denied.".  This occurs when loading a package
>   and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML
>   document. This c an be the result of specifying an incorrect file name
>   when calling LoadPackage or the specified XML file has an incorrect
>   format. End Error Could not load package "\server\path\Package.dtsx"
>   because of error 0xC0011002. Description: Failed to open package file
>   "\server\Package.dtsx" due to error 0x80070005 "Access is denied.". 
>   This occurs when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or
>   loaded correctly into the XML document. This can  be the result of
>   specifying an incorrect file name when calling LoadPackage or the
>   specified XML file has an incorrect format. Source:
>   {4B0EFACA-9BE8-4E0B-AEF7-A1453AF75271} Started:  09:47:51 Finished:
>   09:47:51 Elapsed:  0.047 seconds NULL

The steps are as follows:

1. Create package with 3 user variable `packageId[INT]`, `connectionString[string]`, `sourcePath[string]`

   - `packageId` is some column
   - `connectionString` use in lookups, destination source - define in expression
   - `sourcePath` is `CSV` file
2. Create procedure that insert into table variable and starting job
   example execute:

   (1 row(s) affected)
   Job 'Package' started successfully.
3. Create job

My query:

```
DECLARE @ConnectionString VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @PackageId INT
DECLARE @DataName NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @DtsxName NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @PackagePath NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @DataPath NVARCHAR(200)
SELECT @DtsxName = 'TemporaryPackage'
SELECT @PackagePath = '\\server\path\'
SELECT @DataPath = '\\server\path\Data\'

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PackageImport p WHERE p.dtsxName = @DtsxName AND p.startImport IS NULL)
BEGIN
SELECT @ConnectionString = p.connectionString, @PackageId = p.packageId, @DataName = p.sourcePath
FROM PackageImport p WHERE p.dtsxName = @DtsxName AND p.startImport IS NULL
END

DECLARE @SQLQuery AS VARCHAR(2000)
SET @SQLQuery = 'DTExec.exe /FILE "\"' + @PackagePath + @DtsxName + '.dtsx\""'
 + ' /SET \Package.Variables[User::ConnectionString].Properties[Value];"\"'+ @ConnectionString + '\""'
 + ' /SET \Package.Variables[User::PackageId].Properties[Value];"\"'+ CAST(@PackageId as varchar(10)) + '\""'
 + ' /SET \Package.Variables[User::SourcePath].Properties[Value];"\"'+ @DataPath + @DataName + '\""'

UPDATE dbo.PackageImport 
SET [startImport]=GETDATE() 
WHERE [packageId]=@PackageId AND [dtsxName] = @DtsxName AND [startImport] IS NULL

-- import 
DECLARE @result INT
DECLARE @output TABLE( [ssisOutput] varchar(max) )
INSERT INTO @output

EXEC @result = master..xp_cmdshell @SQLQuery

INSERT INTO PackageHistory(packageId, history)
SELECT @PackageId, ssisOutput FROM @output o 
UPDATE dbo.PackageImport 
SET [stopImport]=GETDATE() 
WHERE [packageId]=@PackageId AND [dtsxName] = @DtsxName AND [stopImport] IS NULL
GO
```

Owner job is SQLSERVERAGENT and have permission read/write to \server\path

Does anyone know what is the problem and could help me?

Answer (score 0):

If this package: \server\path\Package.dtsx, is stored on a different server than the one you are executing it from in SQL Agent, you might be getting a double hop issue.  In any case, it might be worth a try to use a proxy. 
Here is some info on that: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440761(v=sql.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440761%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Package is stored on local server in folder C:\path and this folder shared for user SQLSERVERAGENT. I try executing for another user, who logs on windows authentication and error is thse same.
I try change path from \\server\path to C:\path, did not help.

Comment: The "Access is denied" error is indicating that something is having a problem getting to the path specified.  Since you are calling this via T-SQL, perhaps it is the SQL Server service account which is having the permissions issue and not SQL Agent.

Answer (score 0):

I found simply solution. I change variable 
SELECT @PackagePath = '\server\path\' 
SELECT @DataPath = '\server\path\Data\'

to

SELECT @PackagePath = 'C:\' 
SELECT @DataPath = 'C:\'

I know is not the best solution but I try change permission for sql_serveragent and problem still occured.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution, best for me.
In folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Packages
create folder for my specify packages and data files and change permission for group Users on READ and is work.